# Beyond Compare text-report on all the files from given folders

Tags: scripting, beyondcompare4

my goal is to run text-report on all the files from folder A and B and get as an output html-file with all of the differences between corresponding files. The best would be, if it was just one output file. Is there a way to do it without calling text-report iteratively?

My current script looks like this:

```
log normal log.txt
text-report layout:side-by-side options:ignore-unimportant,display-mismatches
& output-to:"%3" output-options:html-color "%1" "%2"
```

I could use folder-report with links to the output of file comparison, but this does not support text-report options which I am after i.e. ignore-unimportant,display-mismatches. At least as far as I know, but I am new to this tool.

I will be very happy about any answer. If it is really not possible I will try to do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare's text-report scripting command operates on a pair of named files or on selected files. Use the latter method (selected files) to generate a single report for all files in a pair of folders.

```
log normal log.txt
load c:\folder1 c:\folder2
expand all
select all.files
text-report layout:side-by-side options:ignore-unimportant,display-mismatches
& output-to:c:\out.html output-options:html-color
```

To limit the report to files with differences, modify the select command and add a criteria command.

```
log normal log.txt
criteria rules-based ignore-unimportant
load c:\folder1 c:\folder2
expand all
select diff.files orphan.files
text-report layout:side-by-side options:ignore-unimportant,display-mismatches
& output-to:c:\out.html output-options:html-color
```